# Get entire HTML document via jQuery reguardless of top level element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document

I'm trying to get the entire html string of whatever document I have.

Lets say I have a file / document that is this:

```
<body>
<h1>anything</h1>
</body>
```

or something like

```
<form>
</form>
```

I'm looking to get the entire document and all of the html using **jQuery**, I need a way of selecting the top most element and everything within it regardless if it's `<html>`, `<body>`, or `<form>`.

Comment: If you already have a string, what more do you need? If you don't have a string, what are you asking?

Comment: @SLaks It's a bit more complicated then that. I don't have the string, exactly.

Comment: Then what do you have?

Comment: I have the raw HTML input string, but then I edit that using jQuery on the server-side. I need a way to get the edited `dom` using jQuery. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I am a little confused, I want to make sure I understand correctly. What you are working with is not actually rendered to a DOM at the time that you need to select the top element? Whether it is on a DOM or only in a string makes a difference.

Comment: I just finished it search for `document`, and you'll see the bit I needed to make it work [project/index](https://github.com/reggi/jrender/blob/master/index.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('html').prop('outerHTML')` will return a string of the html for the entire document.

If you are concerned that `html` is not the top element, use this code:  `$(document).children().prop('outerHTML')`

That will return the html of the first element one level down from document: http://api.jquery.com/children/

> "The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree"

You can even do this without jQuery. I tested `document.all[0].outerHTML` in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE9 and it works.

You can use `$(document).prop('doctype')` (or `document.doctype` if you don't want to use jQuery) to get the doctype, at least in Chrome 31 and Safari 6.1. Doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: What if there's no `<html>` tag?

Comment: I added another option, in case there is no `<html>` tag

Comment: `document.all[0].outerHTML` isn't doing it for me, the other's are, however it's not grabbing the doctype. Any idea on how to get that too?

Comment: Try `$(document).prop('doctype')`

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox. And I don't know of how to get it all together in one command. You can just string concatenate.